# No output when running `flake8 src` in Docker container

Tags: python, docker

I have built an image `myimage` with Docker using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN pip install flake8
```

and then running

```
docker build -t myimage .
```

.

Now, if I run
`flake8 src`
in the terminal (in a conda environment where I have flake8 installed), then I get a few warnings. But if I run

```
docker run myimage flake8 src
```

then I get no output!

What is the correct way to run flake8 within a docker container so that I can see the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use the `-v` flag to mount the local volume.

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/src:/src myimage flake8 src
```

This works as expected

Comment: Or, even nicer: ```docker run -v $(pwd)/.:/workdir -w /workdir myimage flake8 src```

Answer (score 4):

`flake8 src` has no output try this instead `flake8 -vvv src`

Comment: Thanks! Although I do get output if I run `flake8 src` on its own in the terminal, just not if I run it as `docker run myimage flake8 src`

Comment: You should not have anything .could you please post the output in the question

Comment: When I run `flake8 src` from terminal:
```
src/__init__.py:2:1: F401 '.version.__version__' imported but unused
```

Comment: that has to do with your conda env I think not from flake8, so I think you have the src folder with content in it in your conda

Comment: I ended up solving this using the `-v` flag (see answer below) - thanks for your help!